# JSF pass Object to another page

Tags: jsf, hyperlink, commandbutton

I'm trying to pass an object to another site. So i have my Gallery.xhtml where I set an object as current and redirect to another page:

```
<h:form>
        <a4j:commandButton value="Edit Skin"
            action="#{helloBean.setCurrentSkin(skin)}"
            onclick="window.location.href = 'resources/html/Editor.xhtml';" />
</h:form>
```

But when the getter on the second page is called, the current object is null again.

Is the bean generated for each page? How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Problem was that I declared my bean as `@ViewScoped`, but the proper Tag is `@SessionScoped`. This makes sure that the Bean holds its values for the whole session and not only one view.